# GAE Datastore with Datastore value?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing

I have a client side Java TreeMap that I need to upload to a Datastore entity. The TreeMap ‘Key’ is a form-field name String and the TreeMap ‘Value’ is an encoded String of the associated fields parameters...

There shall be a server side “Report Generator” that fills report line items by selecting values from the TreeMap data object as a function of the form-field names...

On the server side I am looking into a better way to represent the TreeMap data taking advantage of the Datastore ‘index’ capability.

```
  
    I think of the Datastore construction as follows:  
        Key     Unique End user ID String.  
        Value   Properties  
                'FieldID‘           Indexed   
                ‘FieldParameters’   unIndexed
```

To me, this looks like a Datastore design where the Datastore’s value is another Datastore...

Is this possible in GAE?

BTW: I am coding in Java and will most likely use Objectify...

Regards,
Jim...

Answer (score 0):

You can store data as entities with properties in datastore. Go thorough [datastore docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) to get an idea.